# How to change spring resources list name

Tags: spring, spring-boot, http, dto

I have a controller returning all cars in my database. It is achieved by putting the car list into Resources(see the code). **I want to be able to rename the list's name from 'carDTOList' to 'carList". How to do that?**

```
public class CarDTO {

    private String id;
    private UserDTO owner;
    private String brand;
    private String model;
    private String color;
    private String plate;
    private String additionals;
```

---

```
@GetMapping("/cars")
public ResponseEntity<?> getAllCars() {
    List<Resource<CarDTO>> cars = StreamSupport.stream(repository.findAll().spliterator(), false)
            .map(car -> assembler.toResource(modelMapper.map(car, CarDTO.class)))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    Resources<Resource<CarDTO>> carsResource = new Resources<Resource<CarDTO>>(cars, ControllerLinkBuilder
            .linkTo(ControllerLinkBuilder.methodOn(CarController.class).getAllCars()).withSelfRel());

    return ResponseEntity.ok(carsResource);
}
```

---

> {
>       "_embedded": {
>           "carDTOList": [
>               {
>                   "id": "5d5bc8144a8fb83fd42120e1",
>                   "owner": {
>                       "id": "5d5bc8144a8fb83fd42120de",

---

As you see in the response it is set to '**carDTOList**'

Comment: you can rename the return list name . right?

Comment: Yes.Because the class is named as CarDTO, it automatically sets the name carDTOList.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the property name of an embbed collection in Spring Hateos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33289753/how-to-change-the-property-name-of-an-embbed-collection-in-spring-hateos)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Spring annotation:

```
@org.springframework.hateoas.core.Relation(value = "resource", collectionRelation = "resources")
```

to annotate your `DTO` class. So now when you return one element it will be called `resource`. If you return list it will be called `resources`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the `CarDTO` Java name, then take advantage of the Jackson annotation to change naming:

```
@JsonRootName("car")
public class CarDTO {
```

Based on the config you have, when a collection is returned then a `List` suffix will be added.. resulting in `carList`.

Answer (score -1):

you can refactor (rename the file) `CarDTO` class to `CarList`. That should do it.